# ¿Como recordar inicio de sesión en php?

Tags: php

¡Buen día desarrolladores!

Estoy realizando un sistema en el cuál recuerde el inicio de sesión de los usuarios, he utilizado la variable de sesiones de PHP (`$_SESSION`), pero al cerrar el navegador y volver a abrirlo ya no aparece la sesión.

Lo que busco es mas parecido a facebook, el cual no importa que cierre el navegador, aún recuerda mi inicio de sesión.

Así el usuario no tendra que estar logueandose cada vez que cierre el navegador o apague su equipo.

Agradezco de antemano la ayuda. Felíz día.

Comment: pues pon una cookie =)

Comment: Si ya había leído acerca de hacer eso, solo tengo una duda, ¿Cuánto es el tiempo máximo de vida que se le puede otorgar a una cookie?

Comment: je, hubo una pregunta similar que fue eliminada. el tiempo máximo en teoría es 68 años (2147483647 segundos) aunque dependiendo del sistema y el php (32 o 64 bits) puede que el bug del año 2038 haga que expire inmediatamente. en la práctica con ponerle un año o dos estas bien y dentro de las regulaciones europeas para cookies de sesión (otros países o zonas tienen otras regulaciones)

Comment: otra opción es javascript y [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/API_de_almacenamiento_web)

Comment: Ohhh muchas gracias, solo una pregunta más... ¿Tienes algún documento o tutorial que me recomiendes para aprender sobre cookies?

Comment: en MDN hay info https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies y un [ejemplo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie/Simple_document.cookie_framework) ,  si el proyecto pasa de cierta complejidad lo mejor es usar un framework, para php un framework liviano es [codeigniter](https://codeigniter.com/) , uno no tan liviano pero con mas chiches [laravel](https://laravel.com/).

Comment: Muchas gracias...